# How to keep video playing when going back to previous page in JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have a page that has a table whose rows are links to other pages.
When there is a click on a row (link), I set location to that URL like this:

```
window.location=mytable.rows[temp_no].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
```

And in one of those link, a video player starts to play a file in the link and I want it to keep playing when I go back to the previous page so that I can listen to the music when browsing other links.
I go to the previous page with:

```
window.location.href="..";
```

This destroys everything i.e. video player naturally. I can't popup a new window or open video player in a new window since this application works on devices which have single browser window.

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 2):

Of course it does. Changing the location causes the full page to be unloaded and the new one to be loaded.

If you do not want this behaviour you'll have to use AJAX to reload only parts of your site.

Opening the video in a popup window would be another solutionbut new windows are usually annoying, so provide the user e.g. with a "open video in new window" link.

Edit: In this case - assuming the TV browsers have sane JavaScript engines - use AJAX.
Another "solution" would be adding an `onbeforeunload` event to request confirmation from the user before he navigates away from the page.

Without being able to use a new window or AJAX it is impossible unless you use frames and just load another page in a different frame.

Comment: I can't popup a window because this application works on televisions which have only 1 browser page. So simply I use url to visit links and go back. Any other comments ?

Comment: I can't use AJAX either. That's why I ask this question. User already wants to leave the page so no need anything to be confirmed.

Comment: You're going to want to use AJAX for a single page view, so you can load page segments without actually navigating away from the current page. This is well beyond the scope of a Q&A post, but not incredibly complicated. There are plenty of places to learn about ajax online.

Comment: Learning is not the problem. I am not allowed to use it. Thanks for your comments

Comment: I don't understand. The user wants to leave a page, so you are required to let him leave the page. But you want to know how to NOT let the page change? This isn't possible with current technologies, or doesn't make sense. I think more information would be helpful.

Comment: Just curiosity, why aren't you allowed to use it? Anyway, I've updated my answer again.

Comment: I let the page change. I just want to learn that is there a way to keep video player when going back to previous pages or is there a way to go back to previous page without destorying everything in the current page ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [window.open](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) on your videos in a different window so the parent window can navigate wherever.

Keep in mind that you'll have to disable any pop-up blocker.

** **UPDATE** **

If you need everything in the same window, consider using some [iframe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames) to view other pages. The advantage of iframes is that they have their own CSS styles, Javascript sandbox so any page viewed within an iframe does not (generally) affect it's parent container. Of course, there are ways to communicate between an iframe and it's parent and vice versa. But this is out of the question scope.

Comment: I have to play videos on the same page because this is an TV Application so there is only 1 window. Any other comments ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking about iframe too but never did it before. So I'll figure out something.